# Calling a method with a pointer receiver by an object instead of a pointer to it?

Tags: function, pointers, go, methods, call

`v` is an object of `Vertex`, and `Scale` is a method for a pointer to `Vertex`. Then why is `v.Scale(10)` not wrong, given that `v` isn't a pointer to a `Vertex` object? Thanks.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y float64
}

func (v Vertex) Abs() float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y)
}

func (v *Vertex) Scale(f float64) {
    v.X = v.X * f
    v.Y = v.Y * f
}

func main() {
    v := Vertex{3, 4}
    v.Scale(10)
    fmt.Println(v.Abs())
}
```

Answer (score 13):

[Spec: Calls:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls)

> A method call `x.m()` is valid if the [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) of (the type of) `x` contains `m` and the argument list can be assigned to the parameter list of `m`. If `x` is [addressable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) and `&x`'s method set contains `m`, **`x.m()` is shorthand for `(&x).m()`**.

The compiler sees that `Scale()` has a pointer receiver and also that `v` is addressable (as it is a local variable), so `v.Scale(10)` will be interpreted as `(&v).Scale(10)`.

This is just one of the many conveniences the spec offers you so the source code can remain clean.

Answer (score 4):

It's the Go automatic dereferencing:

From https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values:

> As with selectors, a reference to a non-interface method with a value receiver using a pointer will automatically dereference that pointer: pt.Mv is equivalent to (*pt).Mv.

Comment: Actually this is not a method value but a simple method call, so the [Spec: Calls](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls) section is relevant.

Comment: but it is the opposite in my example. in `v.Scale(10)`, `v` isn't a pointer, and `Scale` expects a pointer receiver.

Comment: Tim, true. See @icza answer for the relevant section