# What is the method set of `sync.WaitGroup`?

Tags: go

I have this simple program below

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    wg.Add(1)

    go func() {
        fmt.Println("starting...")
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        fmt.Println("done....")
        wg.Done()
    } ()

    wg.Wait()

}
```

Notice that I use `var wg sync.WaitGroup` as a value, not a pointer. But the [page for the sync package](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/) specifies that the `Add`, `Done` and `Wait` function take a `*sync.WaitGroup`.

Why/How does this work?

Comment: A you'r right..

Comment: I just realized I didn't read your question correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) of [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) is the empty method set:

```
wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(wg).NumMethod())
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/k3Xqqd0TWx)):

```
0
```

This is because all the methods of `sync.WaitGroup` have pointer receivers, so they are all part of the method set of the `*sync.WaitGroup` type.

When you do:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup

wg.Add(1)
wg.Done()
// etc.
```

This is actually a shorthand for `(&wg).Add(1)`, `(&wg).Done()` etc.

This is in [Spec: Calls:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls)

> If `x` is addressable and `&x`'s method set contains `m`, `x.m()` is shorthand for `(&x).m()`.

So when you have a value that is addressable (a variable is addressable), you may call any methods that have pointer receiver on non-pointer values, and the compiler will automatically take the address and use that as the receiver value.

See related question:

[Calling a method with a pointer receiver by an object instead of a pointer to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38481420/calling-a-method-with-a-pointer-receiver-by-an-object-instead-of-a-pointer-to-it/38481697#38481697)

Answer (score 2):

In your case you are modifying a global `wg` object, if you pass it to a function you have to use pointer because you need to modify the object itself. If you pass by value, inside your function you will be modifying a copy of it, not the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation [WaitGroup](https://godoc.org/sync#WaitGroup) :

> A WaitGroup waits for a collection of goroutines to finish.  The main
>   goroutine calls Add to set the number of  goroutines to wait for. Then
>   each of the goroutines  runs and calls Done when finished. At the same
>   time,  Wait can be used to block until all goroutines have finished.

From your Question

> How does this work?

So for `Add` method is set the number of goroutine your called. From your code you have only one :

```
func main() {
    wg.Add(1)

    go func() {
        fmt.Println("starting...")
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        fmt.Println("done....")
        wg.Done()
    } ()

    wg.Wait()

}
```

so it will tells goroutine to wait and print the result.
as for `wg.Done()` this is for telling the one gouroutine has finished to work. and it tells to the `add` to decrement to `-1`. You can see the code below How `Done`  method works :

```
// Done decrements the WaitGroup counter.
func (wg *WaitGroup) Done() {
    wg.Add(-1)
}
```

and finally for the `Wait` method this is for blocking goroutine until the WaitGroup counter is zero.

And another:

> Why ?

from your code above if you don't use `WaitGroup` you will not be able to print the result from the goroutine.

All in all you can read it in the documentation.