# Call struct literal's method

Tags: go

This code works fine:

```
feedService := postgres.FeedService{}
feeds, err := feedService.GetAllRssFeeds()
```

But this code gives me error:

```
feeds, err = postgres.FeedService{}.GetAllRssFeeds()
```

> controllers\feed_controller.go:35: cannot call pointer method on
>   postgres.FeedService literal controllers\feed_controller.go:35: cannot
>   take the address of postgres.FeedService literal

Why this two pieces of code is not equal ?

Here is a struct declaration:

```
type FeedService struct {

}

func (s *FeedService) GetAllRssFeeds() ([]*quzx.RssFeed, error) {
```

Comment: "Why this two pieces of code is not equal ?" because the language spec says so. The error message is pretty self explanatory, or?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `FeedService.GetAllRssFeeds()` method has pointer receiver, so a pointer to `FeedService` is needed to call this method.

In your first example you use a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) to store a `FeedService` struct value in a local variable. Local variables are [addressable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators), so when you write `feedService.GetAllRssFeeds()` after that, the compiler will automatically take the address of `feedService` and use that as the receiver value. It is a shorthand for:

```
feeds, err := (&feedService).GetAllRssFeeds()
```

It is in [Spec: Calls:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls)

> If `x` is addressable and `&x`'s method set contains `m`, `x.m()` is shorthand for `(&x).m()`.

In your second example you don't create a local variable, you just use a struct [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals), but by itself it is not (automatically) addressable, so the compiler cannot obtain a pointer to `FeedService` value to be used as the receiver, and hence cannot call the method.

Note that it is allowed to take the address of a composite literal *explicitly*, so the following also works:

```
feeds, err := (&postgres.FeedService{}).GetAllRssFeeds()
```

This is in [Spec: Composite literals:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals)

> [Taking the address](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) of a composite literal generates a pointer to a unique [variable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables) initialized with the literal's value.

See related questions:

[What is the method set of `sync.WaitGroup`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477951/what-is-the-method-set-of-sync-waitgroup/42480671#42480671)

[Calling a method with a pointer receiver by an object instead of a pointer to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38481420/calling-a-method-with-a-pointer-receiver-by-an-object-instead-of-a-pointer-to-it/38481697#38481697)