# Object instantiation by reference

Tags: go

Here is a sample of Go code which I do not really understand:

```
type MyClass struct {
    field1      string
    field2      string
}
...
objectinstance1 := MyClass{field1:"Hello", field2:"World"}
objectinstance2 := &MyClass{field1:"Hello", field2:"World"}
```

I can do exactly the same thing with `objectinstance1` and `objectinstance2` (method call for example) with the same syntax.

So I do not understand the role of the & operator. What I understand is that `objectinstance1` contains an object whereas `objectinstance2` contains a pointer.

It is for me the same thing in C than the difference between char and char*.

But in this case I should use -> instead of . (dot)?

Comment: See realted / possible duplicates: [Calling a method with a pointer receiver by an object instead of a pointer to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38481420/calling-a-method-with-a-pointer-receiver-by-an-object-instead-of-a-pointer-to-it/38481697#38481697); and [Pointer methods on non pointer types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46956290/pointer-methods-on-non-pointer-types/46956348#46956348); and [What is the method set of sync.WaitGroup?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42480671/1705598) and [Call struct method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42643854/1705598).

Comment: As a side note: in Go, there is no notion of objects. `struct != object`, as detailed in http://spf13.com/post/is-go-object-oriented/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference is not visible because it’s  hidden in 2 things:

1. Operator `:=` which assigns  value and  type for a variable simultaneously. So it looks like `objectinstance1` and `objectinstance2` are the same. But in fact first is a `MyClass` instance and second is a pointer to it. It will be more palpable if use long-form operator:

   var objectinstace1 MyClass = MyClass{}
   var objectinstance2 *MyClass = &MyClass{}

If you omit `*` or `&` variable and type become incompatible and assignment fails.

2. Implicit pointer indirection. Go does it automatically in statements like `ptr1.Field1` to access a specific field in struct by pointer to it.

   Only on rare cases when there’s ambiguity you have to use full form:

   *ptr1.Value1

   or sometimes even:

   (*ptr1).Value1

**UPDATE**:

Explicit pointer usage for disambiguation:

```
type M map[int]int

func (m *M) Add1() {
    // this doesn't work -  invalid operation: m[1] (type *M does not support indexing)
    // m[1] = 1

    // the same - invalid operation: m[1] (type *M does not support indexing)
    // *m[1] = 1

    // this works
    (*m)[1] = 1
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/JcXd_oNIAw

Comment: Thanks but what kind of ambiguity can occur ?

Comment: @Bob5421 in maps for example. Go didn’t compile until I write `(*ptr)[key]`. Otherwise I get error like ‘pointer is not subscriptable’.

Answer (score 3):

The `&` operator gives you a pointer to a struct, while not using it gives you the struct value.

The biggest place this is relevant is when you pass this struct over to another function - if you pass the pointer that you made using the `&` operator, the other function has access to the *same* struct. If that function changes it, you've got the changed struct as well.

If you pass the variable that you made without the `&` operator, the function that you pass it to has a *copy* of the struct. There is nothing that that function or any other function can possibly do to change what you see in your variable.

This effectively makes the value variable safe for use across multiple go routines with no race conditions - everyone has their own copy of the struct.

If you pass the pointer made with `&` to other go routines, all have access to the *same* struct, so you really want that to be intentional and considered.

Answer (score 0):

```
But in this case i should use -> instead of . (dot) ?
```

No. Golang is not C is not Golang. In Golang there *is no* `->`. You use dot (`.`) for pointers aswell. Golang is meant to be simple, there is no point in introducing another operator if the intention is clear (what else would `.` on a pointer mean than calling a method?)

Answer (score 0):

In go, the [`&` operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) takes the address of its argument and returns a [pointer](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types) to the type of the argument.

Pointer indirection happens automatically so there is no `->` operator, the dot operator handles all field (member) operations and accesses for all types, whether a pointer or a struct.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "reflect"
)

func main() {
  type Foo struct{ name string }
  foo1 := Foo{"Alpha"} // A plain struct instance.
  foo2 := &Foo{"Bravo"} // A pointer to a struct instance.
  fmt.Printf("foo1=%v, name=%v\n", reflect.TypeOf(foo1), foo1.name)
  fmt.Printf("foo2=%v, name=%v\n", reflect.TypeOf(foo2), foo2.name)
  // foo1=main.Foo, name=Alpha
  // foo2=*main.Foo, name=Bravo
}
```