# Where does Go define that p.Field (as opposed to (*p).Field) is a valid syntax even when p is a pointer to a struct?

Tags: pointers, go, syntax

Here is my Go program.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    p := &Person{"Jack"}

    // The following statement makes sense. We dereference the
    // pointer to reach the Person object and then retrieve its Name
    // field.
    fmt.Println((*p).Name)

    // But the following statement does not make sense. How does
    // this code work by retrieving the Name field directly from the
    // pointer without dereferencing it?
    fmt.Println(p.Name)
}
```

Here is the output.

```
$ go run foo.go 
Jack
Jack
```

When `p` is of type `*Person`, i.e. a pointer to `Person`, how is it legal to access its field `Name` without dereferencing it? I see all Go tutorials using the syntax `p.Name` instead of `(*p).Name` but where exactly the Go language defines `p.Person` as a legal syntax?

Answer (score 3):

[Spec: Selectors:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors)

> The following rules apply to selectors:
>
> [...] if the type of `x` is a named pointer type and `(*x).f` is a valid selector expression denoting a field (but not a method), **`x.f` is shorthand for `(*x).f`**.

The language spec helps you with the pointer syntax to make it feel you're not even using pointers in some cases. Dereferencing a pointer to access its field is one of them. Also you can call methods that have pointer receiver on non-pointer values if they are addressable, see [Calling a method with a pointer receiver by an object instead of a pointer to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38481420/calling-a-method-with-a-pointer-receiver-by-an-object-instead-of-a-pointer-to-it/38481697#38481697)

Also you can index and slice array pointers, e.g. if `a` is a pointer to array type:

- `a[x]` is shorthand for `(*a)[x]`
- and `a[low : high]` is shorthand for `(*a)[low : high]`.